# Simulating diffusion from bulk to individual particles

Tags: simulations, diffusion, brownian-motion

I have a 2 compartment simulation. The first compartment simulates reactions using [ODE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation)s. The second compartment uses Brownian motion. I want to be able to have molecules from the ODE compartment diffuse into the Brownian compartment.

It would seem I need to answer this question:

What physics/maths governs the rate of diffusion out of a volume? Can I simply use [Fick's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fick%27s_laws_of_diffusion)?

Answer (score 1):

In a volume $V$, a large number number of particles starting to move according to Brownian motion at time $t=0$ from the position $x_0\in V$ will exit from $V$ at a rate that depends on time, on the geometry of the volume $V$, and on the position $x_0$. For instance in one dimension, particles diffusing from $x_0>0$ will enter the region $x<0$ at time $t$ with probability density
$$ p(t)=\frac{x_0}{\sqrt{4\pi Dt^3}}\exp\left(-\frac{x_0^2}{4Dt}\right).\tag{1}$$
(1) is called *Smirnov density*.

Let us note $q(x, t; x_0,t_0)$ the probability of being at $x$ at time $t$, when we started in $x_0$ at time $t_0$. We are interested in
$$Q(t; x_0,t_0)=\iiint_Vq(x,t;x_0,t_0)\mathrm d^3x$$
the probability of being in $V$ at time $t$. 
Starting from the diffusion equation 
$$\partial_tq(x,t;x_0,t_0)=D\Delta_xq(x,t;x_0,t_0)$$
we obtain after integration over $x$ and using the fact that $\Delta_{x_0} Q=\Delta_x Q$ and $\partial q/\partial t_0=-\partial q/\partial t$
$$\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t_0}=-D\,\Delta_{x_0}Q(t;x_0,t_0).$$
As it is a diffusion equation where the variable are the initial conditions, it is called a *backward diffusion equation*. We now can set $t_0=0$ for simplicity. The solution we want is obtained with the initial boundary condition 
$$Q(0;x_0)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}1&\text{if $x_0\in V$},\\0&\text{otherwise}.\end{array}\right.$$
You can check that $$Q(t;x_0)=\iiint_V \frac{\mathrm d^3x}{(4\pi Dt)^{3/2}}\exp\left(-\frac{(x-x_0)^2}{4Dt}\right).$$
And the exit rate at time $t$ is 
$$p(t)=\frac{\partial Q}{\partial t}(t,x_0).$$

Comment: So, I need to evaluate the final equation at each timestep?

Comment: @RRs_Ghost. I have answered the question "What physics/maths governs the rate of diffusion out of a volume?" and my answer shows how it works. Depending on how you perform your simulation, this answer might be helpful or not.

Answer (score 0):

Geometry: Area of orifice, length of orifice

Difference in concentrations which will need to be modeled over time.

Square root of the density: inversely proportional to sqrt of mass of particles. Assuming this is gaseous phase, the density is directly related to mass.) Look up Graham's Law of Diffusion.